# Add watermark to PDF file using PDFSHarp with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, pdf, watermark, pdfsharp

I am using PDFSharp in my VB.Net program and I can't get the Watermark to work.
I am trying to place a Watermark with a specific height and in a specific location. The code processes without error but there is no watermark in the file.

Here is the function. I pass the pdf filename and two string variables that I concatenate.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub PDFWatermark(ByRef PDFName As String, ByRef PDFProject As String, PDFQty As String)
    Dim Watermark As String
    Watermark = "Project: " + PDFProject + " - Project Qty: " + PDFQty

    Dim PDFemSize As Integer = 10
    Dim PDFFont As New XFont("Times New Roman", PDFemSize, XFontStyle.BoldItalic)
    Dim PDFDocument = PdfReader.Open(PDFName)
    If (PDFDocument.Version < 14) Then
        PDFDocument.Version = 14
    End If

    Dim page As PdfPage = PDFDocument.Pages(0)

    'Get an XGraphics object for drawing beneath the existing content.
    Dim gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page, XGraphicsPdfPageOptions.Prepend)

    '// Create a string format.
    Dim Format As New XStringFormat()
    Format.Alignment = XStringAlignment.Near
    Format.LineAlignment = XLineAlignment.Near

    '// Create a dimmed red brush.
    XBrush Brush = New XSolidBrush(XColor.FromArgb(128, 255, 0, 0))

    '// Draw the string.
    gfx.DrawString(Watermark, PDFFont, Brush, New XPoint(100, 100), Format)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

It does not appear that you are actually saving the changes you made to the PDF in memory, try saving the file using the `.Save` method:

```
PDFDocument.Save(fileName)
```

Also, you need to dispose of the `XGraphics` object, you may run into a memory leak issue:

```
Using gfx as XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page, XGraphicsPdfPageOptions.Prepend)
...
End Using
```

Comment: Also, thank you for the tip on disposing of the XGraphics!!!